# How to make backticks `` be treated as quotes in VIM?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vscodevim

I am writing in TypeScript and would like commands like `ciq` to let me change the inner contents of a template literal. However, the `q` part of the command seems to only treat single and double quote marks as valid. Is there any easy fix for this?

Comment: Minor correction: [apostrophes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Typographic_apostrophe_in_8-bit_encodings) are what you call single quote marks. The characters you show are [backticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtick).

Comment: And I think the command "Change Inside Bacticks" `ci\`` works.

Comment: There is no `iq` text object in Vim. The correct text object is ``:help i` ``, as hinted by @phd.

Answer (score 1):

There is `i'` for single quotes, `i"` for double quotes, and `` i` `` for backticks, but there is no `iq` text object in Vim.

If *you* have a `iq` text object, then it must be provided by some third-party plugin, in which case *you* will have to read its documentation and, possibly, use its issue tracker.

Comment: Thank you so much! I meant to mention that I am using the VSCode VIM plugin, I will check what plugins they include by default.

Comment: I replaced the Vim tag with the vscodevim tag as this has nothing to do with Vim.